# Solvability of an inequality $a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0\leq x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a_i$, $i=0, \ldots, n-1$ are positive numbers with sum less than 1, can we claim that the following inequality:
$$a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0\leq x^n$$
has a solution in $(0,1)$ for arbitrary $n>2$?

Answer (score 3):

I think Alan Chung's answer is sufficient for this problem. But let me spell out the details.

If you define $f(x) := x^n - (a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0)$ on $[0,1],$ note that $f(0) = -a_0 < 0$ and $f(1) = 1- (a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 + a_0) > 0.$ Since $f$ is continuous, there must be $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0) = 0,$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem. This $x_0 \in (0,1)$ is your solution, it satisfies $$a_{n-1} x_0^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x_0 + a_0 = x_0^n,$$
and in particular, the inequality you seek.

If you think about the continuity of $f,$ and the fact that $f(1) > 0,$ $f$ will be positive in some small interval $(\delta,1) \subset (0,1),$ which means
$$a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 < x^n \qquad \text{for all } x \in (\delta,1),$$
so you actually have infinite solutions to your inequality, all bunched up near $1.$

Answer (score 2):

Yes this should be true. If you plug in $x=1$ both sides, you get a strict inequality $a_0 + a_1 + \dots + a_{n-1} < 1.$ Now, the point is that the left and right hand side are both continuous, so there must exist some $x \in (0,1)$ (basically some $x$ very close to $1$) that satisfies the inequality.

Comment: That was my reasoning also, but is there a way to be more formal?